# Downloaded Image in AsyncTask result is null

Tags: android, imageview

I've downloaded in image with Asynctask. HandleImageRequest request an image path from MyPHP. I then download the image from the url. I then set that downloaded bitmap to an imageview after decoding it. This doesn't work. I also try to just get the string of the returned bitmap. But the bitmap is null.

HandleImageRequest returns a URL that is readable. **I'm having a hard time finding where I am going wrong in downloading the image from the URL**. If the image was to big, would I have recievied an error, or would the bitmap become null?

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.uploadedImage);
        uploadB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
        uploadB.setOnClickListener(handler);
        Log.v("On create", "CREATED");
    }

    View.OnClickListener handler = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.v("HIT", "HIT");
            UploadImage();
            Next();

        }

    };

    public void Next()
    {
        Log.v("BITMAP OF IMAGE", newImage.toString());
        image.setImageBitmap(newImage);
    }

    public void UploadImage() {


        @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak") AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> k = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {
            ProgressDialog loading;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Uploading Image", "Please wait...");
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap s) {
                loading.dismiss();
                // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,s , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                newImage = s;

            }

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... bitmaps) {
                Bitmap imageIcon = null;
                HandleImageRequest hir = new HandleImageRequest();
                result = hir.ImageHttpRequest(UPLOAD_URL, tag);
                try {
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new java.net.URL(result).openConnection();
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    conn.connect();
                    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                    imageIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return imageIcon;
            }
        };
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11/*HONEYCOMB*/) {
            k.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        } else

        {
            k.execute();
        }
    }
```

If I delete the log inside method Next() that calls for bitmap.toString(), I don't get errors.

```
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9b985420: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9b983320)
V/HIT: HIT
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9b985420: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9b983320)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9b985420: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9b983320)
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=24KB, data=30KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=24KB, data=30KB
I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9b985420: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9b983320)
I/chatty: uid=10080(com.example.matth.downloadimage) RenderThread identical 3 lines
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9b985420: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9b983320)
```

If i leave the log message inside Next(). I get the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.matth.downloadimage, PID: 21040
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.matth.downloadimage.MainActivity$override.Next(MainActivity.java:55)
                      at com.example.matth.downloadimage.MainActivity$override.access$dispatch(Unknown Source:96)
                      at com.example.matth.downloadimage.MainActivity.Next(MainActivity.java:0)
                      at com.example.matth.downloadimage.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:47)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeI
```

Either way, the imageView doesn't update. The original image is removed, but not replaced after the OnClickListener is activated.

Comment: Any logs or error messages? Does your app has internet permission?

Comment: @stanleyKou Updated.

Comment: An `AsyncTask` is _asynchronous_. When you call `UploadImage()`, that task's `doInBackground()` runs on a separate thread, but execution will continue immediately on the current thread, calling `Next()` before the `AsyncTask` has completed. Move the `Next()` call to `onPostExecute()`, after you assign `newImage`.

Comment: Oh man, thank you! For some reason this didn't work previously, but I was also having a different issue before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your code here

```
UploadImage();
Next();
```

You are calling the `Next` function as soon as you call the `UploadImage` function. since `UploadImage` is working on background thread, your Next function will be automatically called in the UI thread as that is not blocked. Change your call of Next function and put it in the `PostExecute` of the `AsyncTask`